# How to merge strings from 3 different objects in a list?

Tags: javascript

What I want to do is merging 3 strings according to the sequence in both the lists.

For example, in an array I have these 3 items which have their data in **string** form:

```
1: {
    permissionIDList: "1,2,3"
    permissionNameList: "Admin Role,Admin Role,Bulletin Board"
    permissionTypeList: "view,edit,view"
}
```

I want to merge the lists and map it into both value and label so that it will become:

```
0: {value: 1, label: Admin Role - view}
1: {value: 2, label: Admin Role - edit}
2: {value: 3, label: Bulletin Board - view}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Array.reduce` implementation

```js
const data = {
    permissionIDList: "1,2,3",
    permissionNameList: "Admin Role,Admin Role,Bulletin Board",
    permissionTypeList: "view,edit,view",
};
const [permissionIDList, permissionNameList, permissionTypeList] = [data.permissionIDList.split(','), data.permissionNameList.split(','), data.permissionTypeList.split(',')];
const merger = permissionIDList.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
  acc[curr] = {
    value: curr,
    label: `${permissionNameList[index]} - ${permissionTypeList[index]}`
  }
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(merger);
```

If your final data response is an array, you can make use of `Array.map`

```js
const data = {
    permissionIDList: "1,2,3",
    permissionNameList: "Admin Role,Admin Role,Bulletin Board",
    permissionTypeList: "view,edit,view",
};
const [permissionIDList, permissionNameList, permissionTypeList] = [data.permissionIDList.split(','), data.permissionNameList.split(','), data.permissionTypeList.split(',')]
const merger = permissionIDList.map((node, index) => ({
  value: node,
  label: `${permissionNameList[index]} - ${permissionTypeList[index]}`
}));
console.log(merger);
```

Comment: I would suggest moving the split of `permissionNameList` & `permissionTypeList` outside the reduce / map functions for performance reasons!

Comment: @AmithRaravi agreed and updated

Comment: @AmithRaravi can you explain to me more about how moving the split outside of the reduce/map functions will improve the performance? I'm still new and want to also learn about optimizing the performance.

Comment: @Lance when we are doing the split inside a loop like map or reduce, each time when the loop executes, the string split executes and will generate new memory allocation for each variable.

Comment: @Lance here the lenth of each key after aplit is 3. so totally 3 * 3 = 9 memmory allocation happens for single execution if the split is performed in the loop. And the loop runs for 3 times, this will make 37 memeory allocations.

Comment: @Lance If this is moved outside the loop, only 3 arrays will be generated, each with 3 elements, whch will make 9 allocations instead of 27.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation @Nitheesh, you've taught me a few new things today, really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This code gives what you need:

```
const strings = {
    permissionIDList: "1,2,3",
    permissionNameList: "Admin Role,Admin Role,Bulletin Board",
    permissionTypeList: "view,edit,view"
}
const permissionIDList = strings.permissionIDList.split(',');
const permissionNameList = strings.permissionNameList.split(',');
const permissionTypeList = strings.permissionTypeList.split(',');

const result = [];

for(let i = 0; i < permissionIDList.length; i++){
  result.push({
    value: permissionIDList[i],
    label: permissionNameList[i] + " - " + permissionTypeList[i]
  });
}

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another implementation could be:

```
const value = {
    permissionIDList: "1,2,3",
    permissionNameList: "Admin Role,Admin Role,Bulletin Board",
    permissionTypeList: "view,edit,view",
}

Object.entries(value).map((item,i) => {
    const permissionNameList = value['permissionNameList'].split(','[i];
    const permissionTypeList = value['permissionTypeList'].split(','[i];
    const permissionIDList = value['permissionIDList'].split(',')[i];

return {
    value: permissionIDList,
    label: `${permissionNameList} - ${permissionTypeList}`
  }

})
```

Comment: I like @Nitheesh answer